# how to : get datas from another table by specified column?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model

i have two tables

1. //users
   id
   username
   password
2. // profiles
   user_id
   logo

i want that get profile information who has user_id equals logged user id but i can't do that . 
how can i do ?

/profile model

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

//client controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Models\Profile as Profile;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $profile = Profile::find(Auth::user()->id);
        return view('client.profil')->with($profile);
    }
}
```

i got this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'profiles.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `profiles` where `profiles`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

normally it could be like that : select * from profiles where user_id = 1
// 1 is logged user_id

Answer (score 2):

First, you're not using a primary key. That's okay, but you need to tell Eloquent. In your `Profile` model, make sure you've set your `$primaryKey` to `null`.

```
protected $primaryKey = null;
```

Then, you'll need to define the inverse of the relationship in your `App\User` model:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

And what you really want is not to query the profile by user id, but to load the user with it's profile, so let's look at that:

```
$user = auth()->user()->load('profile');
$profile = $user->profile;

return view('client.profil', compact('profile'));
```

Comment: i got this error

    Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Comment: @Hannik That's because you don't `return` out of your `public function user()` in your `Profile` model. `return $this->belongsTo('App\User');`

Comment: same error : Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Comment: Uh huh. and do you have a currently logged in user when you run this code? Also, do all users have a profile?

Comment: it works thanks and i wonder that why we use load function . why didn't use model orm structure like find or findBy or why didn't work the code which is in my first question , $profile = Profile::find(Auth::user()->id); , why ?

Comment: @Hannik By defining out relationships in our model, we're better able to control where our logic resides. The `->load `method tells Laravel that we want our `Model` to load some other relationships. In this case, `profile`. The benefit to this is that you have a single point of failure if your relationship doesn't work; the model definition. The downside to the other answer is that now you've defined this in a controller and have to hunt for it, which goes against Laravel's design pragma

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this..

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Models\Profile as Profile;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $profile = Profile::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
        return view('client.profil')->with($profile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Share you answer, so other will get help. Thank you

Comment: Downsides to this method. 1 Relationships defined in a controller. Non-portable code, goes against Laravel's design pragma. Just because it "works" doesn't mean it's correct. Keep that in mind.